# How to call testCaseRetrieveByReleaseId() method in Spira soap API v3.x?Getting empty response

Tags: soap

### ArrayOfRemoteFilter remoteFilters = new ArrayOfRemoteFilter(); JAXBElement jaxString= CreateJAXBString("Release", "9879"); System.out.println("jax string returned iss"+jaxString.getValue()); RemoteFilter remoteFilter = new RemoteFilter(); remoteFilter.setPropertyName(CreateJAXBString("Release", "ReleaseId")); remoteFilter.setStringValue(jaxString); // remoteFilter.StringValue = "Test Case 1"; remoteFilters.getRemoteFilter().add(remoteFilter); System.out.println("remote filters"+remoteFilters.getRemoteFilter().get(0).getStringValue().getValue()); // Create RemoteFilter ArrayOfRemoteTestCase remoteTestCase = soap.testCaseRetrieveByReleaseId(9879,remoteFilters ,1, 9999); // System.out.println("retrieved some values from"+remoteTestCase.getRemoteTestCase().toString()); for (int h = 0; h < remoteTestCase.getRemoteTestCase().size(); ++h) { System.out.print("test values" + remoteTestCase.getRemoteTestCase().get(h).getName().getValue()); System.out.println("test" + remoteTestCase.getRemoteTestCase().get(h).getDescription().getValue()); } System.out.println("List size is"+remoteTestCase.getRemoteTestCase().size());

Comment: Please answer this asap.I have also tried using the below code as 
soap.testCaseRetrieve(remoteFilters, 1, 9999).However,this returns same result irrespective of remote filters i.e even with empty remote filters.Please help

Comment: Any help would be appreciated